# how to stop when user not to redirect to anotherpage if he click on a div

Tags: html

Here i have two div Like

```
<div class="Div1">
<div class="Div2">
<a href="#/Hello">Click On Me</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here my aim is to when user click on only Div2 it should Redirect to another page Not when click on Div1
Its Working fine in Googlchore but not in IE11

Comment: What exactly is your question? You've put a link in div2 so yeah... when clicking on that it redirects you to another page. And why the CSS tag? This is just HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do this. One like this

```
<div class="Div1"></div>
<div class="Div2">
    <a href="#/Hello">Click On Me</a>
</div>
```

or like this

```
<div class="Div1">
   <div class="Div2">
      <a href="#/Hello">Click On Me</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Div1{
  padding:10px;
}
.Div2{
     background-color:black;
}
```

So you will have an area 10px where the user clicks on Div1 and it won't redirect.
You can use this to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it seems you misunderstood the behavior here. When you click on div1 or div2 there happens nothing. Only if you click on your Link Tag `a` you will be redirected.
Your both `div` elements have the same size. Both enclose your Link Tag. So they have the same height and 100% width by default. Your Link Tag is as wide as the text inside.
Only your Link Tag handle here a click event.

Seems this is not your full source code, so a correct answer is also somewhat difficult.

Comment: Here i have separate css for Div1 And div2 didnt have any css even its not woring in IE11

Comment: Handling click events it's JavaScript part. Here an example: `<div class="Div1" onclick="theFunction()">` But take care. This event will also fire when you click the Link Tag. Right solution is having elements in each div which handle the click.